# ChromeOs application testing and deploying

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, deployment, google-chrome-app

I ported my OPA on ChromeOs but I have several questions:

1) How to test it? My web App is covered by mocha/chai/sinon + karma as test runner. Is the any solution for testing chrome apps.

2) Is the any way to automatically deploy it?

Comment: This question is incomprehensible. What is an OPA? Is it a web app or a Chrome App? What research have you already done?

Comment: OPA === One Page application.
It is built by backbone/marionette.
Now it's running on phantom as webkit headless but i want run on chromeOS engine

Deploying is manually after package is done we load it to chrome webStore panel